# Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation (gradle 2.4 ,android studio)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just update Android Studio and I can't build any project, even newly created ones.

The error I got is:

Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-2.4**.zip'.

what should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have two famous way for this problem:

**1- update the gradle:**

*step 1:*

Get latest version supported by Android Studio from:

[https://services.gradle.org/distributions](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/)

*step 2:*

Extract the gradle file and install to dists folder(gradle folder): default location is: C:\Users[username]\gradle\wrapper\dists

*step 3:*

Open Android Studio: File/Settings/Gradle/Service directory path: (Change to folder you set above) and Click ok.

Status on bottom should indicate it's busy & error should be fixed.

*step 4:*

restart Android Studio

**2- Delete the .gradle folder:**

default location is:

C:\Users[username]\gradle\wrapper\dists

after that open Android Studio and make a new project (might need to reastart).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it help me to solve problem.

Answer (score 8):

In Eclipse, for me it resolved as follows:

- Delete:

  - **`workspace/yourProject/.gradle`** (folder)
- In Eclipse:

  - Right click on **`ProjectName > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project`**

[image]

- Wait:

  - Download all dependencies
- Done!

Comment: I don't see a .gradle folder I see a gradle folder though which contains wrapper folder and inside the wrapper there is a jar and a properties files. Is this the one I should delete?

Comment: Me neither. But there is a folder called ".gradle" in the C:\Users\[UserName]  . When it's removed and refreshed from eclipse, it just reappears without solving the problem.

Comment: @VivekShukla Open the project in a folder. There is the .gradle folder

Answer (score 5):

The link you are using is wrong.

Use:

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip

Check the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Comment: Support for builds using Gradle versions older than 2.6 was removed in tooling API version 5.0

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while trying to import a Gradle project on Eclipse. It turned out that Eclipse was not able to access a particular hidden folder (jars-3) in `username/gradle/caches/jars-3`. I tried modifying it myself, but even as an administrator, I could not.

I had to use the steps in [this article](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-fix-the-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container-error-on-windows-10) to resolve the problem.

Open an elevated command prompt, and enter the following, replacing"FULL_PATH" with the affected folder.

> ```
>  TAKEOWN /F X:\FULL_PATH_HERE
>  TAKEOWN /F X:\FULL_PATH_HERE /r /d y
>  icacls X:\FULL_PATH_HERE /grant Administrators:F 
>  icacls X:\FULL_PATH_HERE /grant Administrators:F /t
> ```

Finally, close the Command Prompt and try changing the permissions for the folder.
After that, delete the imported project and reimport it. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error using Eclipse and Buildship. None of the other fixes worked. The problem turned out to be in my Eclipse preferences. I believe it was a mismatch between the workspace JDK and/or Gradle home and the ones in the Gradle config. The following steps fixed the problem:

- Set the Java JRE to the JDK specified in the Gradle configuration
  (Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs)
- Set the Java JRE and the
  Gradle home in the Eclipse Gradle config (Preferences -> Gradle).

Then refresh the Gradle project (Project -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check to obvious stuff first!

I know this is a very old question, and it has a good accepted answer (and other good ones too!) but this was my issue today with this and I'm happy to say in this case it was the simple fix.

In Eclipse - the Error msg showed in **Problems** tab in Eclipse
*"**Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https:...'** "*

Looked in the **Console** tab for message, in my case it was

> Could not get unknown property 'blabblah' for root project...

The problem was that I had removed a property from my gradle.properties file and hadn't checked that it was no longer used.
I was distracted by the **Problems** tab message and googled that instead of looking at the console. Wasted more minutes than I care to admit.

Check the obvious stuff first! (like the console messages!)