# Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed in android studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

**Error: Access is denied**

I have recently installed Android Studio and I am running it from behind my organisation proxy. I have gone through 100 of links for this problem and I am not able to find the solution.

**What I have done till now :**

1. In **gradle.properties** I have written following lines

   ```
   systemProp.http.proxyHost=sy*********om
   systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
   systemProp.http.proxyUser=RAGU
   systemProp.http.proxyPassword=W********
   systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=*****om

   systemProp.https.proxyHost=sy**********om
   systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
   systemProp.https.proxyUser=RAGU
   systemProp.https.proxyPassword=W********
   systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=*****om
   ```
2. In **Project Structure** in JDK location I have entered the location of my jdk ie. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66` instead of using the embedded JDK.
3. **My build.gradle :**

   ```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
    common to all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {
      repositories {
         jcenter()
      }

      dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
    }

      allprojects {
        repositories {
           jcenter()
         }
     }

     task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
   ```

**My logs**

you can see the logs via this link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7ZLoWnEHDkac2thbXRTNEduTkZPSkFYNW56UVV3UzhmZ3NZ

Whenever I try to sync the gradle this error pops up . What can I do to resolve this error.

Comment: What about the error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation (gradle 2.4 ,android studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887623/errorcould-not-run-build-action-using-gradle-installation-gradle-2-4-android)

Answer (score 0):

I had very ugly issues with gradle wrapper and gradle-wrapper.properties until i found this [Gradle proxy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22666646/2413627). I tested it and it worked like a sharm.The command was this

> gradle -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.proxyUser=username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyUser=username -Dhttps.proxyPassword=password wrapper

I ran it in the Android Studio terminal with Windows proxy disable.My PC is running on Windows 10 x64 Versión 10.0.16299.15 with Android Studio 3.0.1

I hope this help you out there.Happy new year!!